# Get the identifier of a table and display in another table

Tags: laravel, laravel-8

Hello i need help the pictures below represent my problem. Thank you in advance for your help

In my select I retrieved the list of campaigns (in the Campaign table). Now in my logic (Which is the creation or I add one of an appointment, another different table) image 1 I would like to retrieve the identifier of the chosen campaign when adding it.

My select

```
<div class="col-6">
    <select class="form-control" name="nomCampagne">
        <option selected disabled>Sélectionnez la campagne</option>
        @foreach ($mycampagnes ?? '' as $item)
            <option value="{{ $item->id }}">{{ $item->nom }}</option>
        @endforeach
    </select>
</div>
```

My controller

```
 $appointment = Appointement::create([
    'user_id' => auth()->user()->id,
    // 'campagne_id' => $mycampagnes->id,
    'nomCampagne' => $request->nomCampagne,
    'date' => $request->date
]);
```

Comment: At first glance, it looks ok to me. What is your issue?

Comment: and the issue is???